# Atomic file transfer from R

Tags: r

I need to push a file to a remote server from within R.  It needs to be atomic (or nearly atomic).  Conceptually, my idea was to first scp it to a tmp directory, and then move it to its final destination. What's a good way to do this from R?  I'm on a Linux system, if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you provide a more reproducible example or be more specific about what you are trying to do? For example, what do you mean by atomic? Binary data?

Comment: I suspect "atomic" here means the file magically appears in one place complete and not gradually as it gets transferred. The remote server should never see half a file. Right?

Comment: Yes @Spacedman that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `system` calls in R. Something like:

```
system("scp foo.dat remote:/tmp/foo.dat.tmp")
system("ssh remote mv /tmp/foo.dat.tmp /drop/foo.dat")
```

you might need some extra parameters to `ssh`

you might also want to generate a random number for the temporary file name.

of course this need scp/ssh server and `mv` at the server, so easiest with GNU/Linux at both ends.

and you should probably check the return status of the `scp` command to see if it completed successfully or not before attempting the `mv`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, and it works, except any command I submit to my R shell (from emacs or from Vim) while the second command is still running is ignored by R, which is really weird behavior.  I may submit a second stackoverflow question about this.

Comment: The problem I was having had to do with ssh eating subsequent commands sent to the R shell. c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838273/calling-ssh-with-system-in-r-shell-eats-subsequent-commands/28842197#28842197